# How to open existing project in React Native in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to open the following simple project On **React Native** using the visual studio 2017
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

how I can do that, as you know there is no .sln file in **React Native** project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the repository using `git clone https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app` , once you have a local version you can open it like a normal project in VSCode or you can launch it from the terminal as shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)

Comment: The answer you gave is about VS Code not about VS 2017